# Move One VM on Google cloud to another VM

Tags: virtual-machines, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

We have one VM (compute Engine) in one of our project on Google Cloud. We need to transfer this VM to another project on Google Cloud. This new project is located in another Google Cloud account.
How can I do it?

[image]

Thanks for your help.
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to actually 'move' the VM, but you can recreate it:

Prerequisite: the account used must have right to access to all projects

- Go to project A

1 - Turn VM off (recommended or the image can be corrupted)

2 - [Create an Image](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/create-delete-deprecate-private-images#bundle_image).

- Go to project B

3 - Create new Compute Engine instance using the [custom image](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance#sharedimage), images are global resources.